# How to get current logged in user in my java web app but not in servlet context?

Tags: java, servlets, guice-servlet

After get current user info I store it in session for later use, but most of the situation I need to get current user info not in a servlet context. Such as in non-servlet environment I need to call something like this:

```
UserUtils.getCurrentUser();
```

Any ideas on this?

Further question, I use Guice-servlet, maybe there is a way to inject current user?

Comment: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()//using spring-security

Answer (score 0):

If i where you i would realy consider to use [spring security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security)!
It provides everything you need for security!

Answer (score 0):

What security framework you are using? Try [Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) it can integrate with Guice quite easily [Shiro Guice](http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html)  and you can use to annotation to handle Permission like this and other cool stuff.

```
 @Requires("supervisor")
 public void securedResource() {
 ...
 }
```